# Return result from incomplete data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have two huge tables `avg_rent` and `avg_sale`. They contain average prices for apartments broken down by location, apartment size and other factors. The data in those tables may be incomplete.

For example in table `avg_sale` I may have:

```
id  | apartment_size_id | county | city | median_sale
100 | 1                 | 1      | 4    | 800
101 | 4                 | 1      | 4    | 600
102 | 6                 | 1      | 4    | 650
```

And in table `avg_rent` I may have:

```
id  | apartment_size_id | county | city | median_rent
300 | 1                 | 1      | 4    | 300
301 | 2                 | 1      | 4    | 250
302 | 3                 | 1      | 4    | 200
303 | 4                 | 1      | 4    | 250
305 | 6                 | 1      | 4    | 200
```

I want to create a `SQL` query or `plpqsql` function that would aggregate `median_sale`, `median_rent` and `apartment_size_id` columns and fill in missing data with -1 or something. In case of the example would return this (there are total of 6 size categories):

```
apartment_size_id | median_rent | median_sale
1                 | 300         | 800
2                 | 250         | -1
3                 | 200         | -1
4                 | 250         | 600
5                 | -1          | -1
6                 | 200         | 650
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you just need a full outer join.

Comment: If you have two huge tables and only size sizes, how is the data combined?

Comment: I left a lot of columns out. Data should be combined by county, city or some other columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `left join` for this, assuming you have a table of apartment sizes:

```
select a.apartment_size_id, coalesce(r.median_rent, -1) as median_rent,
       coalesce(s.median_sales, -1) as median_sales
from apartment_sizes a left join
     avg_rent r
     on a.apartment_size_id = r.apartment_size_id and
        r.county = 1 and r.city = 4 left join
     avg_sale s
     on a.apartment_size_id = s.apartment_size_id and
        s.county = 1 and s.city = 4;
```

This also assumes that you want the information for a single county/city pair.

I would recommend that you represent the missing values using `NULL` rather than `-1`, unless you have a good reason for choosing -1.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `full outer join` and `COALESCE`

```
select 
    r.apartment_size_id,
    COALESCE(r.median_rent, -1)  as median_rent,
    COALESCE(s.median_sale, -1)  as median_sale
from avg_rent r
FULL OUTER JOIN avg_sale s 
on r.apartment_size_id = s.apartment_size_id
```

This query definitely gives only those `apartment_size_id` present in either `avg_rent` and `avg_sale`
If you have a `apartment` table which is having all `apartment_size_id` info then you can do the same with `left join` and `COALESCE`

```
select 
    a.apartment_size_id,
    COALESCE(r.median_rent, -1)  as median_rent,
    COALESCE(s.median_sale, -1)  as median_sale
from apartment a
LEFT JOIN avg_rent r on a.apartment_size_id = r.apartment_size_id
LEFT JOIN avg_sale s on a.apartment_size_id = s.apartment_size_id
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5d713/1)

Comment: This will not return row 5.